QuestPDF with AWS Lambda. Get Exception add license System.IO.IOException: Read-only file system : '/var/task/gdal_wrap.so'
Describe the bug
Included new version QuestPdf to generate in AWS Lambda, but when I tried to register Licence, gave me a exception. I think is because can't write any file in path that is not /tmp
System.IO.IOException: Read-only file system : '/var/task/gdal_wrap.so'
enter image description here
To Reproduce
Using AWS Lambda to generate a Pdf.
Expected behavior
Generate a PDF normally
Environment
It's serverless and run linux based.
.net 6
Dockerfile
....
WORKDIR /var/task/
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
COPY --from=build /src/$ARCHIVE_FILE_PATH .
RUN ls -la
RUN yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
RUN amazon-linux-extras install epel -y
RUN yum install -y libgdiplus
ca-certificates
fontconfig
freetype
libX11
libXext
libXrender
Works normally added on API controller, but not in AWS Lambda (serverless). Try to remove license line or add CHMOD, but don't works...

Please format your Dockerfile correctly, either using the various "code" formating suggewsted in the editor (or this: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Include the error message as text, instead of an external image.
My guess is that you are trying to copy the file gdal_wrap.so into the WORKDIR. Make sure that you have write permissions into /var/task.

AWS Lambda doesn't allow changing permissions for /var/task, that is clear to me, but gdal_wrap is a file inside a package whose path I can't manipulate. It's all about QuestPDF License, at least I think so.
